# update Entity Model Framework dynamically

Tags: wcf, dynamic, model, entity, odata

I want to update ADO.Net Entity Data Model programmatically, so that the EDM is getting the newest version of the database (new tables, values etc.). Once a database table is added or altered the Entity model is out of date. Recompiling the data service is not an option.

I know that it is possible to update the EDM, by clicking in the Model Designer, Update Model from Database.

Do you know any solution? Is there any tool for update entity model programatically?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [EDM Generator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387165.aspx)
Take a look at [DBMetal](https://code.google.com/p/dblinq2007/wiki/DbMetal) too.
But I suggest you to get rid of designer generated models and use code first approach: lightweight POCOs and fluent mappings (fluent => no attributes, mapping class is easy to manage). It's much more easier to maintain. + EF supports Code First Migrations.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, this requirement isn't really supported by EF.  Generating the model again will perform code generation. However, you will still have to compile and then re-cache meta data and views.  This becomes a very expensive proposition for EF.

If your schema is changing often you may not even want a relational database.  You should look at schema-less persistence (nosql).  Raven DB, for example would much more easily allow you to dynamically change the shape of what you at saving.

Comment: I'm using WCF OData service as my application Data Provider. I heard there is a facility to update Entity Model Framework dynamically. Do you have any idea?

Comment: No, I'm not aware of any way to dynamically change the schema using OData.